# Is repeating the section title in the first sentence good writing style?

Tags: writing-style, style-manuals

In a number of structure formats I am very tempted to re-state the title of sections in the first section, i.e. if the given section is “Expected Results”, I tend to want to start by saying “The expected results of this study are [...]”.

I feel it sounds a lot better, regarding the text's flow as I would read it, but then again, I am repeating information which was basically obvious from the section name.
Any idea if there is a good writing style convention for or against this?